# how to convert json object to string in android..?

Tags: android, json

I want to convert from `JSONObject`

`{"CNo":80,"CName":"ganesh","CMail":"ganesh@ganesh.com","CMailType":"home","CPhNo":9878987776,"CPhNoType":"home","ClientNo":1}`

to

`{\"CNo\":80,\"CName\":\"ganesh\",\"CMail\":\"ganesh@ganesh.com\",\"CMailType\":\"home\",\"CPhNo\":9878987776,\"CPhNoType\":\"home\",\"ClientNo\":1}`

Comment: Do you have a json-formatted *string* and you want to escape the `"` using backslash in this string? Or do you start with a JSONObject, and want to convert it to a string?

Comment: yeah, I suggest you clarify your question a bit. And use code formatting, please.

Comment: hi aioobe i just need the below format from a existing json object..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope this helps. Just learnt it yesterday :)

```
JSONObject foo = yourJSONOject;
String uid = foo.get("CNo").isString().toString();
String type = foo.get("CName").isString().toString();
.
. //for each Key field.
```

I am not sure why you have put the escapes in the string, but you can call `append()` and get the OP as you want it.

Comment: do we have anything like javascriptserializer as we use in .net?

Comment: im sorry, im not familiar with .net. you can define a "\" and append it/insert it where you require.

Answer (score 11):

Try to use `toString()` on your JSON object

Comment: ya i checked.. its the same object which is returning.. to the stringentity.. !! im assigning the json.tostring() to a stringentity variable so that i can use this to post to a .net rest client

Answer (score 2):

Below code will convert the given JsonObject to string.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String bodyInStringFormat = gson.toJson(passYourJsonObjectHere);
```