# How to stop Moshi from parsing a specific object attribute

Tags: android, json, retrofit, moshi

My JSON response (from a server) has attributes that are JSON objects, but I don't want to parse them all, instead I want to keep some of them as a JSON-encoded String.

For instance:

```
{
"date": "23-03-2019",
"changed": true,
"data": {
    "login": "9999999",
    "loginFormatted": "999 99 99",
    }
}
```

Here I want to parse "data" attribute as string. How can I do it? (I am using Retrofit v2.4.0 and Moshi v1.5.0)

My model class for response:

```
public class Response {
    @Json(name = "date")
    public long date;
    @Json(name = "changed")
    public boolean changed;
    @Json(name = "data")
    public String data;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert json object to string in android..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049582/how-to-convert-json-object-to-string-in-android)

Comment: did you try to `@SerializedName` as a string in pojo ?

Comment: @MD Do you mean Gson?

Comment: try like `@SerializedName("data") String data;`

Comment: @MD instead of Moshi, I tried to use Gson, as you said. But java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 46 path $.data error is thrown

Comment: can you post your model of response class that you're using in retrofit  ?

Comment: @MD I posted what you asked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190600/discussion-between-m-d-and-tm13).

Answer (score 7):

When Moshi looks at the hierarchy of `Response` class, it decides to use a `JsonAdapter<String>` to parse the field `data`. So the solution is to tell Moshi not to use `JsonAdapter<String>` to parse it but delegate the task to our `JsonAdapter`.

Talk is cheap, here is the code.

```java
class KeepAsJsonString {
  public void run() throws Exception {
    String json = "" +
      "{\n" +
      "\"date\": \"23-03-2019\",\n" +
      "\"changed\": true,\n" +
      "\"data\": {\n" +
      "    \"login\": \"9999999\",\n" +
      "    \"loginFormatted\": \"999 99 99\"\n" +
      "    }\n" +
      "}";

    Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().add(new DataToStringAdapter()).build();
    JsonAdapter<Response> jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(Response.class);

    Response response = jsonAdapter.fromJson(json);
    System.out.println(response.data); // {"login":"9999999","loginFormatted":"999 99 99"}
  }

  static class Response {
    @Json(name = "date")
    public String date;
    @Json(name = "changed")
    public boolean changed;
    // Ask moshi to forward the intermediate result to some function with a String annotated with @DataString,
    // in our case, DataToStringAdapter.fromJson() and DataToStringAdapter.toJson()
    @Json(name = "data")
    public @DataString String data;
  }

  @Retention(RUNTIME)
  @JsonQualifier
  public @interface DataString {
  }

  static class DataToStringAdapter {
    @ToJson
    void toJson(JsonWriter writer, @DataString String string) throws IOException {
      // Write raw JSON string
      writer.value(new Buffer().writeUtf8(string));
    }

    @FromJson @DataString
    String fromJson(JsonReader reader, JsonAdapter<Object> delegate) throws IOException {
      // Now the intermediate data object (a Map) comes here
      Object data = reader.readJsonValue();
      // Just delegate to JsonAdapter<Object>, so we got a JSON string of the object
      return delegate.toJson(data);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new KeepAsJsonString().run();
  }
}
```

In Kotlin it can look like this:

```
@JsonQualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD, AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER, AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
annotation class DataString

internal class JsonObjectToStringJsonAdapter {

    @ToJson
    fun toJson(@DataString s: String): String {
        return s
    }

    @FromJson
    @DataString
    fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader, adapter: JsonAdapter<Any>): String {
        val jsonObject: Any = reader.readJsonValue()!!
        return adapter.toJson(jsonObject)
    }
}
```

---

Update:

As Eric Cochran mentioned, there will be a more efficient way (`JsonReader.readJsonString()`) to read JSON as string when this [issue](https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/675) is fixed.

Comment: the `@ToJson` isn't going to work as you might expect. this currently will write a string, instead of the raw json. you might want `writer.value(new Buffer().writeUtf8(string))`.

Comment: to fromJson is going to be costly currently. keep an eye on https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/675 (previously an issue of the same name as this question: https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/318) for the real feature you want.

Comment: `writer.value(BufferedSource)` is available in Moshi 1.6 to anyone who may be on an older version and noticed this didn't compile.